# Play 2.x Variables and Scripts

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there equivalent syntax to the following in the routes file for Play 2.x?

```
%{context = play.configuration.getProperty('context', '') }%
GET    ${context}         Secure.login
```

In other words, can I still execute scripts and use variables in the routes file in Play 2.x?

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be done in the routes file. The routes file is compiled, and doesn't support expression evaluation anyway.

You may be able to do what you want by transforming the request -- see [Scala Interceptors](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaInterceptors). In your `onRouteRequest` method, you can change the uri (e.g. by calling `request.copy(uri = "/changedUri")`). This will add a small penalty to all requests -- an alternative would be to route to a standard login action that would redirect to the real login action, depending on config.